# R ggplot2: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic error in Bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am getting this error while plotting a bar graph and I am not able to get rid of it, I have tried both qplot and ggplot but still the same error.

Following is my code:

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(ggplot2)

 #Investigate data further to build a machine learning model
 data_country = data %>%
           group_by(country) %>%
           summarise(conversion_rate = mean(converted))
  #Ist method
  qplot(country, conversion_rate, data = data_country,geom = "bar", stat ="identity", fill =   country)
  #2nd method
  ggplot(data_country)+aes(x=country,y = conversion_rate)+geom_bar()
```

Error:

```
  stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic
```

Data in data_country:

```
    country conversion_rate
    <fctr>           <dbl>
  1   China     0.001331558
  2 Germany     0.062428188
  3      UK     0.052612025
  4      US     0.037800687
```

The error is coming in bar chart and not in the dotted chart.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

First off, your code is a bit off. `aes()` is an argument in `ggplot()`, you don't use `ggplot(...)` + `aes(...) + layers`

Second, from the help file `?geom_bar`:

> By default, geom_bar uses stat="count" which makes the height of the
>   bar proportion to the number of cases in each group (or if the weight
>   aethetic is supplied, the sum of the weights). If you want the heights
>   of the bars to represent values in the data, use stat="identity" and
>   map a variable to the y aesthetic.

You want the second case, where the height of the bar is equal to the `conversion_rate` So what you want is...

```
data_country <- data.frame(country = c("China", "Germany", "UK", "US"), 
            conversion_rate = c(0.001331558,0.062428188, 0.052612025, 0.037800687))
ggplot(data_country, aes(x=country,y = conversion_rate)) +geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes that worked thanks for explaining it, I am little new to this appreciate your help

Comment: Clarification, `aes` is in fact a function. The argument to `ggplot` is `mapping`. We provide that mapping through the `aes` function, so you see the pattern `ggplot(df, aes(...))` a lot. But the pattern ggplot(data_frame) + aes(x =X, y=Y) is fine too. Aside from possibly improved readability, calling `aes` separately can be used to modify the aesthetics on a premade plot: p <- ggplot(iris) + aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length) + geom_point(); q <- p + aes(y=Petal.Length)

Comment: As of 2020 (and long before), `ggplot(...) + aes(...) + layers` is fine.

Answer (score 10):

You can use geom_col() directly. See the differences between geom_bar() and geom_col() in this link https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html

> geom_bar() makes the height of the bar proportional to the number of cases in each group If you want the heights of the bars to represent values in the data, use geom_col() instead.

```
ggplot(data_country)+aes(x=country,y = conversion_rate)+geom_col()
```

Comment: Can confirm I had been having this issue and this was the simplest solution.

Answer (score 9):

when you want to use your data existing in your data frame as y value, you must add stat = "identity" in mapping parameter. Function geom_bar have default y value. For example,

```
ggplot(data_country)+
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = country, y = conversion_rate), stat = "identity")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same and this may also work

```
p.Wages.all.A_MEAN <- Wages.all %>%
                  group_by(`Career Cluster`, Year)%>%
                  summarize(ANNUAL.MEAN.WAGE = mean(A_MEAN))
```

> names(p.Wages.all.A_MEAN)
>   [1] "Career Cluster"   "Year"   "ANNUAL.MEAN.WAGE"

```
p.Wages.all.a.mean <- ggplot(p.Wages.all.A_MEAN, aes(Year, ANNUAL.MEAN.WAGE , color= `Career Cluster`))+
                  geom_point(aes(col=`Career Cluster` ), pch=15, size=2.75, alpha=1.5/4)+
                  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color="#993333",  size=10, angle=0)) #face="italic",
p.Wages.all.a.mean
```