# Error- State_count() must not be used ,. How to solve this?

Tags: r, geom-bar

She wants to find out crimes in the USA for various states. So she plots the data set "USArrests" to construct a bar chart of the number of murders in different states.

Following command is giving error :
ggplot(USArrests, aes(x = row.names(USArrests), y = USArrests$Murder, lab)) + geom_bar() + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))

Error : 
"stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic". What can she do to correct this?

1. Should I remove row.names — it should be x = USArrests$State ??
2. Should I use theme(axis.angle.x = 90) instead of current one?
3. Will geom_histogram() be better than Geom_bar?
4. Or Should I use geom_col() instead of geom_bar()?

Please do suggest correct command.  Thanks

Comment: Please if you think your question has been solved, check it as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issue, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679057/r-ggplot2-stat-count-must-not-be-used-with-a-y-aesthetic-error-in-bar-graph). Just use `geom_col` instead of geom_bar, and also add `row.names` as a new variable to avoid further problems:

```
USArrests$states <- row.names(USArrests)

ggplot(USArrests, aes(x = states, y = Murder)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
```