# In R, how do I create a bar graph using a categorical x and the average of a numeric y with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using R version 3.5.1.

I started with [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679057/r-ggplot2-stat-count-must-not-be-used-with-a-y-aesthetic-error-in-bar-graph), and used the code suggested by the top comment on my own dataset, where `time_len` is a categorical variable telling how long it takes to play game i, with values of short, medium, and long; `num_fans` is a numeric variable telling how many fans game i has:

```
ggplot(cdata) +
  aes(x = time_len, y = num_fans) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Here is the plot:

[image: bar chart of the data]

I created the bar chart using the code above, but the problem is that the `num_fans` variable looks like it is a total. I want it to show the average for each category.

EDIT: here is a sample of my data.

```
  game_id min_players single_player max_players family_game avg_time time_len year life avg_rating
1  161936           2         multi           4      family       60    short 2015    4    8.65105
2  187645           2         multi           4      family      240     long 2016    3    8.45420
3   12333           2         multi           2       small      180     long 2005   14    8.32843
4  193738           2         multi           4      family      150   medium 2016    3    8.28646
5  162886           1        single           4      family      120   medium 2017    2    8.39401
6   84876           2         multi           4      family       90   medium 2011    8    8.12803
  geek_rating   rating age owned num_fans
1     8.49375 8.572400  13 47498     2168
2     8.16391 8.309055  14 23989     1594
3     8.18051 8.254470  13 45955     3639
4     8.07144 8.178950  12 21513      835
5     7.96162 8.177815  13 13743     1002
6     8.01120 8.069615  12 49353     1866
```

Again, I am only asking about time_len. Is there a way to show the average of `num_fans`?

Comment: Try replacing the `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` line with `stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun.y = "mean")`?

Comment: It works! Thanks for the comment, but I'm pretty sure you're supposed to respond using the "Post Your Answer" button. Comments are meant to ask questions for further clarification.

Comment: It was a guess. You can post that as an answer yourself if it solves your problem. On my end, I couldn't be sure since I don't have your data & can't actually reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the

```
geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

line with

```
stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun.y = "mean")?
```

(Note: this is the answer contributed by Z.Lin, who told me that I could post it as an answer.)